# Apache Spark API without Spark in python

Tags: python, apache-spark

I love Apache Spark, but often times want to test scripts without actually starting an instance. Does anybody know an implementation of the `SparkContext` interface that doesn't actually use Spark?

In other words, I'd like to be able to do something like this.

foo.py:

```
import pyspark.SparkContext as sc

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
distData = sc.parallelize(data)
distData.map(lambda x: x+1)
```

And then be able to run `python foo.py` as well as `pyspark foo.py` by changing the `import pyspark.SparkContext` line to something like `import pysparkimitator.SparkClone`?

The point would be to have portable scripts that can used without spark for smaller data sets and with spark for larger ones.

**Edit**

The logic behind this question is the 97% of the time, this script will be run with small datasets that do not require distributed processing. The other 3% will require parallelization and it seems unnecessary to make 97% of users install spark for tasks they don't need it for.

Also, things like `groupByKey` don't seem to exist in python (`itertools.groupby` comes close but requires arrays to be sorted first).

Comment: so do you want to run on machines that don't have spark? or you don't want to waste time starting up spark on your machine? initializing a spark context on my local takes around 2 seconds, so it's not that big of a hit.

Comment: @acushner: both :)

Comment: Is launching spark-shell a limitation? It would mean: instead of running "python", you would run "/path/to/spark/bin/spark-shell". Of course, you could not execute your python file.

Comment: @Markon: Yes. The point is to just have a script that the lay user can just run regularly but an advanced user can pass to spark for parallel execution.

Comment: I can't think of anything like that, unfortunately. You could write a bash script, though, that runs the python/spark program.

Comment: how big is it this 97%? are you talking about 5 or 80-90 users?

Comment: @Markon: Let's say it's 1 and I want to get into the habit of programming in an easily distributable manner without actually having to spin up an instance every time I want to do so.

Comment: What is wrong with running in local mode?

Comment: @zero323: Can't run it without having spark installed. Have to start a master instance.

Comment: You need binaries but you don't need running cluster. And the answer to your question is no. There is no such thing and you can be pretty sure there won't be.

Comment: @zero323: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: *"things like groupByKey don't seem to exist in python*" - Apparently you didn't search [the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.groupByKey)

Comment: @cricket_007: Sorry, my statement was unclear. I actually meant that such functions don't exist in python outside of spark.